# How to prevent $ interpretation in JSP to make jQuery templates work

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a page generated with data from both backend and front. The front end is using a jquery template, and page itself is written in JSP, and there is a conflict of using $ sign:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ${title}
</script>
```

For example, I want the above code to be interpreted by front end, but JSP is translating to something else. How do I prevent this from happening?

thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to the top of the page:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>
```

This should only be in the page which defines the template. Include that page from the main page, if you want to use EL in it.

Answer (score 11):

Put backslash before dollar sign and it won't be interpreted as JSP EL.

```
\${title}
```

So, `${1+1}` prints `2` and `\${1+1}` prints `${1+1}`.

Otherwise, you can do what **Jared** says.

Comment: I believe this also works for simple tempalte. The EL ignore solution above seems more generic. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the following for any problematic lines

```
out.print("${title}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not enclose them between jsp:text or move all your template code in a .js file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use this

```
<%="${name}"%>
```